# How do I get params in rails that are only from the URL?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rails mountable gem which fires custom javascript events based on what controller and action being rendered.

I would like to add a feature where the params from the URL are available to event handlers:

```
// 'PATCH /users/:user_id/tasks/:id'
$(document).on('tasks#update', function(data, params){
  console.log(params['user_id'], params['id']);
});
```

For security reasons I would like to limit this to the params which originate from the URL and not from the request body.

Since this is library and not application code I can't just use `URI.parse` as the key mappings are not known.

How do I get a subset of the params that are only the router matches?

Comment: The full source for the gem is at https://github.com/maxcal/pagescript.

Comment: Try `request.env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters']`. If you also want the remaining querystring params(not matched by routing) you can use `request.env['action_dispatch.request.query_parameters']`

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreAngelim, I had totally missed your comment in the noise but it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the controller (or a helper in this case) you can get a subset from `request.path_parameters` and `request.query_parameters`.

```
def body_tag(**opts)
  options = opts.deep_merge(
    data: request.path_parameters.merge(request.query_parameters)
  )
  if block_given?
    content_tag(:body, options) { yield }
  else
    tag(:body, options, true)
  end
end
```